# Attractiveness bias, based on political views

Tags: social-psychology, physical-attraction

I've noticed that if I agree with the political/cultural/religious views of a person, then he looks sort-of beautiful (physical appearance), even if he (or she) happens to be ugly.

I've also noticed that if people disagree strongly with a person's political views, they think he or she is ugly (as an example, think of the many caustic comments on the looks of Hillary Clinton and Donald Trump).

**My question is: What is the name of this phenomenon?**

I know that "Attractiveness bias" is a term describing the opposite phenomenon: if a person looks beautiful, we think he's wise.

But I'm asking here about the **opposite direction**: if a person is wise (according to our subjective opinion, of course), then we think he looks beautiful. I tried googling this but couldn't come up with any discussion of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a negative/reverse [halo effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_effect), aka a [horns (or devil) effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_effect).